# List items can't get multiplied

Tags: python, list

I have a basic question:
There are two lists named `a1` and `b1`. 
If I print out one item of each list, it would be a `float number`, but when I use `a1[i]*b1[i]` in a loop, it gives an error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Why is that?

Comment: What language and can we see the code?

Comment: Add snapshot of you code that will be helpful

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mentioned! Python is the one and here is the piece of the code :

Comment: One of the operands to `*` is a sequence, not a `float`. Show us your data and/or code.

Comment: I could not post all lines. I wish these lines help

b1 = []
b2 = []
f=open('output.txt', 'rb')
lines=f.readlines()
for i in range(0,1100):
        linelist=string.split(lines[i])
        b1.append(float(linelist[1]))
        b2.append(float(linelist[2]))
row1=numpy.asarray(b1)                
row2=numpy.asarray(b2)
print row2


covariance = numpy.zeros((1100,1100))
for i in range(0,1100):
    for j in range(0,i):
        covariance[i][j]=b1[i]*a[j]
        covariance[j][i]=covariance[i][j]

Comment: Thanks everyone, found the error!

Comment: Fered, instead of posting code (or other important additions to a question) in a comment, edit the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `a1` or `b1` is not list of floats but a list of lists of floats.

```
a1=[1.234, 1.234];
a2=[1.234, 1.234];
>>> a1[0]*a2[0]
1.522756

a3=[[1.234], [1.234]];

>>> a1[0]*a3[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 1):

Think @Gille probably got your error.

If all you want to do in your loop is multiply entries together, the fast way would be to use numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.multiply(a1,b1)
```

Cast back to a list if necessary:

```
result = list(result)
```